# Webelement getText() function returns different values on the same element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Following code is used to get text of specified button element with id:

```
 EE__printer-menu__activator
```

In our structure it's `drop-down` and here is `element` with child elements D**OM structure:**

```
<button data-v-12817ac3="" type="button" class="some classes" id="EE__printer-menu__activator"><div class="v-btn__content">
        Printer
        <i data-v-12817ac3="" aria-hidden="true" class="some classes">arrow_drop_down</i>
</div>
</button>
```

The problem is following: when `drop-down` is not expanded and I'm trying to get text of `id="EE__printer-menu__activator"` element using `getText()` I receive :

```
{Printer
arrow_drop_down}
```

which is expected. but when drop-down is expanded and I'm using the same I get only text of first child:

```
{Printer}
```

Can't understand why in this case `getText()` doesn't return `"arrow_drop_down"` text of the last child of selected element.

Answer (score 0):

When `drop down` is not extended then if you pay attention

```
<i data-v-12817ac3="" aria-hidden="true" class="some classes">arrow_drop_down</i>
```

to more particular attribute `aria-hidden` is set to true. so when you are calling `.getText` on `EE__printer-menu__activator`, you are getting both the `text`.

Now, here is a bit assumption that when `drop down is expanded`, then `aria-hidden` value will be set to `false`. causing `.getText()` to `return` what it has, and it does have only first `Printer`.

Comment: Even if drop-down is expanded child element still is:
<i data-v-12817ac3="" aria-hidden="true" class="some classes">arrow_drop_down</i>

Comment: And one additional thing, I understand that aria-hidden attribute doesn't screen allow screen reader to read it, but what effect does it has on webdriver?

Comment: may be the DOM was not refreshed, or may be the element was not rendered properly. put some sleep and see if that helps. if it does not try to refresh and see if that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't be so. The page is the same, the only action that I do is clicking on drop-down. I tried different stuff and all the time when I'm trying to getText of <i> element before expanding d-d I get it correct and always get empty string when I'm trying the same when the d-d is expanded what is very strange to me

Comment: even if the page is same it may trigger some js functions and that may have impact on your automation

Comment: tried sleepers and refresh,
nothing helped,
still can't understand connection of aria-hidden attribute and webdriver and why it can't find the text of this element even if I'm trying to get it directly : //button[@id='EE__printer-menu__activator']/div/i
If I use this xpath in chrome elements tab it finds the element

Comment: But if found it using executeScript innerText function

Comment: Well there's a purpose why `aria-hidden="true"` this is true, and when it should be false.